# c# Remove overlapping parts of two strings

Tags: c#

I have strings s1 and s2 of size 100000.

The front part of s2 is the same as [0~n] to [s1.Lenght - 1] of s1.

I want to find the overlapping part of s1 in s2 and remove it.

example 1)

```
str1 = "abcdefgh"
str2 = "cdefghijklmno";
```

i want: `ijklmno`

example 2)

```
str1 = "abcdefgh"
str2 = "efghijklmno";
```

i want: `ijklmno`

example 2)

```
str1 = "aaabbb"
str2 = "abbbfffxx"
```

i want: `fffxx`

The length of the string is always over 100000 and it takes too long to compare them one by one because it has to be done in real time.

Do you have any good solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe we can help to fix your approach

Comment: So, lastindexof the first char of string B in string A then check if B StartsWith the sub string of A's index to end?

Comment: @CaiusJard that seems a O(n^2) to me. I don't know, from the top of my head, if it can be solved in O(n).

Comment: What percentage overlap are you expecting ?

Comment: @CaiusJard s1 and s2 seem to overlap by more than 50% on average

Comment: And are you looking for the maximum overlap or the minimum overlap? aaabcdbcd vs bcdbcdefg; do they overlap by 3 chars or 6?

Comment: What do you want if there is no overlap at, e.g. with str1="pqr" and str2="abcdef"?

Answer (score 1):

So the substring is always at the beginning? Then this works and is efficient:

```
public static string RemovePartFromStart(string full, string part, out string prefixFound)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < part.Length; i++)
    {
        string part2 = part.Substring(i);
        if (full.StartsWith(part2))
        {
            prefixFound = part2;
            return full.Substring(part2.Length);
        }
    }

    prefixFound = null;
    return full;
}
```

Your samples:

```
var strings = new List<(string part, string full)> { ("abcdefgh", "cdefghijklmno"), ("abcdefgh", "efghijklmno"), ("aaabbb", "abbbfffxx") };
foreach (var x in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(RemovePartFromStart(x.full, x.part, out string prefixFound));
}
```

output:

```
ijklmno
ijklmno
fffxx
```

.NET Fiddle with 100k-length strings: https://dotnetfiddle.net/khomWB
(takes ~0.1sec. for all)

Comment: Unless I misunderstood it, I think this is fairly terrible tbh; if a string a megabyte long overlaps another on the last 2 chars you're going to do just shy of a million substrings to find that out?

Comment: @CaiusJard: i guess you misunderstood. I'm just doing a StartsWith comparison for a substring of the smaller string. Of course the longer the small part is, the more time this approach will take.

Comment: @CaiusJard: obviously it also depends on if there is always an overlapping part or just sometimes.

Comment: Let's say both strings are a megabyte, and they overlap on the last 2 chars; how many strings must be created by repeated substringing to find that out?

Comment: @CaiusJard: i have tested this approach with 10 random string-pairs. The long string had 100000 chars and the part-string had 10000 chars. The method needed ~1 second to determine all results

Comment: @CaiusJard: on .net-fiddle it even only takes 0.1 seconds: https://dotnetfiddle.net/khomWB

Comment: yes! substring is always at the beginning

Comment: You can divide time by ~10 not using substrings: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mspSMj (on my PC, with .NET 6, it's by ~300), not even speaking of memory allocations.

Comment: @SimonMourier interesting

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if the following code answers your question

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string s1 = "cdef";
            string s2 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            Regex regex = new Regex($"(?:{s1}|[{s1}]+)(.*)");
            string result = regex.Match(s2).Groups[1].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Fabio

Answer (score 0):

My take on it using a regex:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
//...
static string NonOverlap(string s1, string s2)
{
    var re = string.Join("?", s1.ToCharArray()) + "?";
    var m = Regex.Match(s2, re);
    int s = m.Index + m.Length;
    return s2.Substring(s);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str1 = "abcdefgh";
    string str2 = "cdefghijklmno";

    Console.WriteLine(NonOverlap(str1, str2));
    str1 = "abcdefgh";
    str2 = "efghijklmno";

    Console.WriteLine(NonOverlap(str1, str2));
    str1 = "aaabbb";
    str2 = "abbbfffxx";
    Console.WriteLine(NonOverlap(str1, str2));

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Outputs:

> ijklmno
> ijklmno
> fffxx

It turns the prefix string, say "abc", into a regex like "a?b?c?" which means each letter is optional so it copes with the case where the overlap starts some way into str1.